# Check <div> at the same level

Tags: xpath

I have  at the same level, and I want the check the value of one div, and retrieve the value of another  using local-name() where possible.

```
                <div class="x-extension-property">
                    <div class="x-extension-property-id">I own a house</div>
                    <div class="x-extension-key"></div>
                    <div class="x-extension-value">This is the value I want </div>
                    <div class="x-extension-data-type"></div>
                </div>
```

In a single Xpath statement I would like to detect that  x-extension-property-id = "I own a house" and when that matches retrieve the value of  x-extension-value which is "This is the value I want"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested it, but something like this should work:

> /div/div[@class='x-extension-property-id' and text() = 'I own a house']/../div[@class='x-extension-value']